# Django Rest Framework: Without Model

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views

I'm working on creating a RESTAPI using DRF(Django Rest Framework). API just receives the users twitter handle and returns his twitter data.

Here, I'm not using model here because it's not required.

**Should I use a serializer here? If so why? Now I'm able to return the data without using a serializer.
Moreover, My API is not web-browsable. How should I make it web-browsable: which is one of the best features of DRF.**

Edit:1

I'm using Functions in Views.

```
@api_view(['GET'])
@csrf_exempt
def getdetails(request):

    call the twitter api
    receive the data
    return HttpResponse(JsonResponse( {'data': {'twitter_id':id,'tweets':count,'Followers':followers,'following':count_follow}}))
```

In the browser I'm just seeing JSON data like this.

{"data": {"twitter_id": 352525, "tweets": 121, "Followers": 1008, "following": 281}}

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `Serializer` for the result

```
class SampleSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    field1 = serializers.CharField()
    field2 = serializers.IntegerField()
    # ... other fields
```

#### Usage

```
my_data = {
    "field1": "my sample",
    "field2": 123456
}

my_serializer = SampleSerializer(data=my_data)
my_serializer.is_valid(True)
data = my_serializer.data
```

You'll get serialized data in `data` variable (you can use `my_serializer.data` directly)

> Should I use a serializer here?

It's up to you, because if you wish to show the response JSON  without any modification from the Twitter API, you can go without DRF serializer. And If you wish to do some formatting on the JSON, my answer will help you

> My API is not web-browsable. How should I make it web-browsable?

Maybe you followed wrong procedure. Anyway we can't say more on this thing without seeing your code snippets

### Update-1

```
from rest_framework.response import Response


@api_view(['GET'])
@csrf_exempt
def getdetails(request):
    call the twitter  api
    twitter_api = get_response_from_twitter()  # Json response
    return Response(data=twitter_api)
```

Comment: hello Jerin. thanks for your response. Modified the question with sample code. Please suggest a way to make it web-browsable

Comment: Thank you jerin. is web-browsable api possible without using Serializer ? If so please let me know how?.

Comment: In your case, `api_view`decorator will do it. Unfortunately, you'd used `HttpResponse` so, it forcefully converted the we-browsable API to an HTML like response

Comment: Did you tried `Update-1` section of my answer? It should work,

Comment: Hello Jerin, I added response Instead of HttpResponse(JsonResponse()). and it worked. Thank you :) it's now web-browsable and yea I haven't used serializer